# How do I reset Gimbal SDK triggers for debugging purposes?

Tags: java, android, sdk, gimbal, proximityapi

I find it really hard to debug my app using Gimbal Places.

I have my Places/Communications set up and sometimes they do fire but once they fire I do not know how to reset the trigger so that I can check if its working. I have to walk up and down the street and then sometimes it does not even fire.

Is there a way to reset the trigger in my program ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.

The easiest way to create Gimbal Place Events, which in turn can generate Communicate Events, is to use a Gimbal Beacon. You can purchase the Series 10 for $5 at the Gimbal Store. Powering the beacon on will trigger a Place Event once it leaves programmable mode, about 10 seconds. Then you can create a departure event by powering the beacon off, by default it will take 30 seconds to depart (configurable in Gimbal Manager). Once you get the departure event you can trigger another arrival event by powering the beacon back on.

You can also use geofences as described above to do this testing if a beacon is not available. The issue with a geofence is generating the departure, which as described above requires you to actually leave the geofence. You can also generate arrival events by uninstalling and reinstalling the application. Each time it starts and you are in the geofence it will generate an arrival event.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use USB Beacons, so you can plug/unplug them for testing. But if you prefer to use geofences there are apps that can fake your location with Android (I guess something similar for iOS).

But the best think to test it are USB beacons, at least for myself.